# While passing Zoho url in Postman , for getting response to generate json data , I am getting this error message as __Invalid clinet___

Tags: postman, zoho, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, zoho-deluge

[View Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2vcL.png)
Can any one give idea about this issue
While I am passing the Url for getting response ,
I need Access token and refresh token through this.
I referred all the sites and Browse the releted video for solution

Comment: You mention that you've referred all sites, but you haven't mentioned what  you've actually tried.  This error is referenced on this site several times and is usually related to the URL being different based on where you are in the world.  I recommend detailing what you've tried and perhaps link to the API documentation.